# zf2 Form message in a tooltip : where does it come from?

Tags: javascript, forms, zend-framework2

Let's say I have a form with an email form element;
when I write for instance 1 letter in this field and I press OK, I get a message in a tooltip, in my language (french) :
"Veuillez saisir une adresse courriel valide" (something like "Please insert a valid email adress" in english !).

I'd like to know **where does this message come from**. I thought from javascript/bootstrap : no result.

Thank you

Comment: From your HTML5 supported browser.

Comment: your zf2 From element most likely has a 'require' => 'required' attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment from @dan-klasson:

When you use `\Zend\Form\Element\Mail` (or EMail?) ZF will render this as `<input type="email">`. This email field is handled and validated by the browser - like date, range and what-ever other new html5 elements exists.

If you think of replacing you validating to html5-browser validation - it's not a good approach, because other browsers could handle different mails different.

Comment: If your question is solved could you accept answer as solution

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)